# understanding debounce. thunks and assignment return

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, underscore.js, lodash, redux-thunk

I'm still trying to understand why thunks are useful. What I have heard are the following:

1. Creates closure around the thunk, which means that context is preserved

Question: Why is context important to preserve if the code block is already held within the function expression?

Example:

```
function debounce(func, delay) {
  var inDebounce = undefined;

  console.log("GOOD DEBOUNCE")

  return function(){
    var context = this, args = arguments

    // why can't context be null? or under debounce?

    clearTimeout(inDebounce);
    return inDebounce = setTimeout(function() {
      return func.apply(context, args)
    }, delay)
  }
}
```

2. Thunks allow for functions to be called repeatedly

I saw an example introducing a thunk like the difference between

let x = 1 + 2
and let x = () => return 1+2

allowing us to return 3 multiple times

```
function debounce2(func, delay) {
  var inDebounce = undefined;
  console.log("BAD DEBOUNCE")
  var context = this, args = arguments
  clearTimeout(inDebounce);
    return inDebounce = setTimeout(function() {
      return func.apply(context, args)
    }, delay)
```

This example did not work. It was called once on document.load, and I could not make any API calls with the app.

EDIT// IGNORE BELOW THIS LINE. I read the docs

So in this case, it makes sense, but how does this make sense?

```
return inDebounce = setTimeout(function() {
  return func.apply(context, args)
}, delay)
```

This line seems like it's returning an assignment?

Answer (score 1):

It returns `inDebounce`. The last piece of code is equivalent to:

```
inDebounce = setTimeout(function() {
  return func.apply(context, args)
}, delay);
return inDebounce;
```